android Manifest merger failed build
please help with manifest merger
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-9731420309932281~5955996158"/>
    <activity android:name=".activity.SplashActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".FruitsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".AlphabetActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".NumberActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".KnowledgeActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".DrawingActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".activity.SettingsActivity"/>

    <service
        android:name=".util.BackgroundSoundService"
        android:enabled="true" />

</application>

Merge Errors Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#infiapp.kidsgame.kidslearninggame.activity.SplashActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for android:exported when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. Kids_Learning_Game.app main manifest (this file), line 16
